# How to use multi-level indexing in pyomo with a set and a rangeset?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyomo

I have multiple levels of indices in my model in `pyomo`, and I need to be able to index variables like this:

```
model.b['a',1]
```

But this doesn't seem possible for some reason.  I can use multilevel indexing like this:

```
model = ConcreteModel()
model.W = RangeSet(0,1)
model.I = RangeSet(0,4)
model.J = RangeSet(0,4)
model.K = RangeSet(0,3)

model.B = Var(model.W, model.I, model.J, model.K)
model.B[1,2,3,0]  # access the variable using the indices - THIS WORKS!!
```

But this does not work, however:

```
model = ConcreteModel()
model.W = Set(['a','b'])
model.I = RangeSet(0,4)

model.b = Var(model.W, model.I)  # I can't even create this - throws exception
```

...it throws the exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot index a component with an indexed set
```

Why does the first one work and not the second one?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when you write

```
model.W = Set(['a','b'])
```

you are actually creating an indexed Set object rather than a Set with the values in the provided list. This is because all Pyomo component constructors treat positional arguments as indexing sets.

You can fix this by adding the "initialize" keyword before your list of values

```
model.W = Set(initialize=['a','b'])
```

The same would be true if you provided a list of integers rather than strings

```
model.I = Set(initialize=[0,1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: okay, thanks.  But, why does `model.W = RangeSet(0,1)
model.I = RangeSet(0,4)` work? I didn't need an "initialize" keyword for those, and those are component constructors.

Comment: RangeSet is a very specialized component that can only be used for the specific case of generating a consecutive range of numbers. It doesn't accept keyword arguments and can only be constructed in three ways

    `model.W = RangeSet(stop)  # returns the set [1, 2, ..., stop]
    model.W = RangeSet(start, stop) # returns the set [start, start+1,...,stop]
    model.W = RangeSet(start, stop, step) # returns [start, start+step, ... end] where end = start+i*step and end <= stop`

Comment: okay, thanks.  This is another relevant question that you might find interesting:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908555/how-to-define-an-integral-as-an-objective-function-in-pyomo/39908672#39908672