# Pyomo Multiple Integrals

Tags: python, pyomo

Is there a continuous (integral) analog to Pyomo's sum function which could do several summations at once

```
sum(model.x[i,j] for i in model.index_is, for j in model.index_js)
```

Heat_Conduction.py in the dae examples has a reference to nested integration, but it is commented out and it throws a ValueError: Integral must be indexed by a Continuous S whenever I comment it back in.

```
# def _obj(m):
#     return Integral(Integral(expr=m.intExp,wrt=m.x,bounds=(0,10)), wrt=m.y,bounds=(0,5))
# m.obj = Objective(rule=_obj)
```

I've searched everywhere, but I couldn't find a working example and I couldn't understand the docs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Integral component is not fully developed and I wouldn't recommend using it. A better way to formulate a continuous integral using Pyomo.DAE components would be to differentiate your integral equation and convert it to a differential equation. See the discussion here: [How to define an Integral as an objective function in pyomo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908555/how-to-define-an-integral-as-an-objective-function-in-pyomo/39960159?noredirect=1#comment75508241_39960159)

Comment: I'm not sure how I could accomplish that with my current model. Is Integral really that unuseable?

Comment: Based on your question on the pyomo forum where you want "the indices of the inner integrals to depend on the outer ones", no there isn't a way to do that with the Integral component. The Integral component was prototyped for simple integrals where the bounds are the entire range of the ContinousSet over which they were declared. In addition, the trapezoid rule is the only numerical integration technique currently available which may not be accurate enough for all problems. Overhauling the Integral component is on my TODO list but I'm not sure when it will be available.